# Flicker when antialiasing a 0.5 point (1 pixel) border of a CALayer on retina screens

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation, calayer, antialiasing

Looking around Stackoverflow you can find some code that allows you to antialias borders of CALayers similar to:

```
layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES;
layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = kCALayerLeftEdge | kCALayerRightEdge + kCALayerTopEdge | kCALayerBottomEdge;
layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = NO;
layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

But for retina displays, it would be nice to draw borders 1 pixel wide. So I changed my border to this:

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 1 / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

The only problem is that afterwards you can see the edges "flicker" as the user scrolls. It is definitely better than with no antialiasing, but not as smooth as I would like. Has anybody figured out  get the layers not to flicker?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very recent, I know, but maybe contentsScale will do the trick. 
See the whole thing in Swift

```
    let layer = view.layer
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.CGColor
    let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
    layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
    layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = [.LayerBottomEdge, .LayerTopEdge, .LayerLeftEdge, .LayerRightEdge]
    layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = false
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```